# Java | Sigar: Getting network traffic

Tags: java, windows, networking, bandwidth

I'm trying to get the network traffic using the below code in Java with the help of Sigar library

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.hyperic.sigar.NetFlags;
import org.hyperic.sigar.NetInterfaceConfig;
import org.hyperic.sigar.NetInterfaceStat;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class NetworkBandwidth {

    private Map<String, Long> rxCurrentMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    private Map<String, List<Long>> rxChangeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Long>>();
    private Map<String, Long> txCurrentMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    private Map<String, List<Long>> txChangeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Long>>();
    private List<String> msg;
    private Sigar sigar;
    private String TAG = "LOG: ", serverCode;
    private volatile boolean stopGettingNetworkBandwidth = false;
    private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    public NetworkBandwidth(String serverCode, ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
        this.sigar = new Sigar();
        this.serverCode = serverCode;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.msg = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            getMetric();
            System.out.println(TAG + "NETWORK INFO: " + networkInfo());
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } 

    private Long[] getMetric() throws SigarException {
        for (String ni : sigar.getNetInterfaceList()) {
            // System.out.println(ni);
            NetInterfaceStat netStat = sigar.getNetInterfaceStat(ni);
            NetInterfaceConfig ifConfig = sigar.getNetInterfaceConfig(ni);
            String hwaddr = null;
            if (!NetFlags.NULL_HWADDR.equals(ifConfig.getHwaddr())) {
                hwaddr = ifConfig.getHwaddr();
            }
            if (hwaddr != null) {
                long rxCurrenttmp = netStat.getRxBytes();
                saveChange(rxCurrentMap, rxChangeMap, hwaddr, rxCurrenttmp, ni);
                long txCurrenttmp = netStat.getTxBytes();
                saveChange(txCurrentMap, txChangeMap, hwaddr, txCurrenttmp, ni);
            }
        }
        long totalrx = getMetricData(rxChangeMap);
        long totaltx = getMetricData(txChangeMap);
        for (List<Long> l : rxChangeMap.values())
            l.clear();
        for (List<Long> l : txChangeMap.values())
            l.clear();
        return new Long[] { totalrx, totaltx };
    }

    private static long getMetricData(Map<String, List<Long>> rxChangeMap) {
        long total = 0;
        for (Entry<String, List<Long>> entry : rxChangeMap.entrySet()) {
            int average = 0;
            for (Long l : entry.getValue()) {
                average += l;
            }
            total += average / entry.getValue().size();
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static void saveChange(Map<String, Long> currentMap,
                                   Map<String, List<Long>> changeMap, String hwaddr, long current,
                                   String ni) {
        Long oldCurrent = currentMap.get(ni);
        if (oldCurrent != null) {
            List<Long> list = changeMap.get(hwaddr);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new LinkedList<Long>();
                changeMap.put(hwaddr, list);
            }
            list.add((current - oldCurrent));
        }
        currentMap.put(ni, current);
    }

    private String networkInfo() throws SigarException {
        String info = sigar.getNetInfo().toString();
        info += "\n"+ sigar.getNetInterfaceConfig().toString();
        return info;
    }

    public void stopGettingNetworkBandwidth(boolean stop){
        stopGettingNetworkBandwidth = stop;
    }

    public void getBandwidth() throws SigarException, InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    try{
                        Long[] m = getMetric();
                        long totalrx = m[0];
                        long totaltx = m[1];
                        System.out.print("totalrx(download): ");
                        System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(totalrx));
                        System.out.print("totaltx(upload): ");
                        System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(totaltx));
                        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (SigarException e){
                        System.out.println(TAG + "Failed to get Network Bandwidth, SigarException >> " + e.toString());
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println(TAG + "Failed to get Network Bandwidth, InterruptedException >> " + e.toString());
                    }
                    if (stopGettingNetworkBandwidth)break;if (stopGettingNetworkBandwidth)break;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

I though I'm getting the network traffic when I browse into internet until I realize I'm getting unexpected result.

I'm developing Server and Client app that communicates inside the LAN, I was expecting `0` as the result of the above code when I didn't use or browse into internet but since the application was communicating inside the LAN, I'm always getting a result.

any idea on how can I get the internet usage `except when the Server and Client is sending or receiving message inside the LAN`?

Comment: Do you mean internet (connecting different network) or Internet (the public Internet)? You host determines if the traffic is on the same network by masking its IP address and that of the destination with its configured network mask. If the results are the same, then the traffic is destined for the local network. If the results are different, then the host sends the traffic to its configured gateway (router). That is probably as close as you can get to what you are asking.

Comment: what I mean is the public internet. . .

Comment: so , a conditional statement whether the result are different or not. let me try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ron Maupin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3745413/ron-maupin) for the idea of having a condition.

Here's how I solved it

I changed the method `getBandWidth()` to `getTraffic()`,

```
public void getTraffic() throws SigarException, InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                long oldReceived = 0, oldSend = 0, newReceived, newSend;

                while (true){
                    try{

                        Long[] m = getMetric();

                        newReceived = m[0];
                        newSend = m[1];

                        if(oldReceived != newReceived || oldSend != newSend){ //if the result is different from the previous

                            oldReceived = newReceived; //put the new result to old result
                            oldSend = newSend; //put the new result to old result

                            if(oldReceived > 999 || oldSend > 999 && oldReceived == 0 || oldSend == 0){
                                System.out.print("totalrx(download): ");
                                System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(newReceived));
                                System.out.print("totaltx(upload): ");
                                System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(newSend));
                                System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                            }

                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch (SigarException e){
                        System.out.println(TAG + "Failed to get Network Traffic, SigarException >> " + e.toString());
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        System.out.println(TAG + "Failed to get Network Traffic, InterruptedException >> " + e.toString());
                    }
                    if (stopGettingNetworkBandwidth)break;if (stopGettingNetworkBandwidth)break;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I realized that I wasn't looking for the bandWidth but the network traffic, and after observing the result, I found out that when my `Server` and `Client` send and received data inside the local network, the result is less than a thousand, and when I'm browsing or downloading the result is equal to a thousand or higher.

I'm not sure if this is reliable solution but for the meantime I'm gonna used this solution until I found a second option.